# How to override Function in C++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

Currently, I am working on c++ project I want to know how I can send an instance of a child class to function use parent as a parameter and execute a function in a child here is an example: I want Child print function to be called

**Parent.h**

```
#ifndef UNTITLED_PARENT_H
#define UNTITLED_PARENT_H


class Parent {

public:
    virtual void printData();
};


#endif
```

**Parent.cpp**

```
#include "Parent.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Parent::printData() {
    cout<<"Parent"<<endl;
}
```

**Child.h**

```
#ifndef UNTITLED_CHILD_H
#define UNTITLED_CHILD_H
#include "Parent.h"

class Child : public Parent{
public:
    void printData();
};

#endif
```

**Child.cpp**

```
#include "Child.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Child::printData() {
    cout<<"Child"<<endl;
}
```

**ParentUser.h**

```
#ifndef UNTITLED_PARENTUSER_H
#define UNTITLED_PARENTUSER_H
#include "Parent.h"

class ParentUser {

public:
    void printer(Parent p);
};

#endif
```

**ParentUser.cpp**

```
#include "ParentUser.h"

void ParentUser::printer(Parent p) {
    p.printData();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Parent.h"
#include "Child.h"
#include "ParentUser.h"

int main() {

    Child child;
    ParentUser parentUser;
    parentUser.printer(child);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make your argument a reference, not a value - you are [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing#274634)

Comment: What is your observed (mis) behavior ?

Comment: what do u mean by  observed (mis) behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `void printer(Parent p);` will create a new object of type `Parent` using a copy constructor your compiler automagically creates for you. You need to change it to take a **reference** instead:

```
void printer(Parent& p);
```

This will make sure that `p` is actually a reference to `child`, not a new `Parent` created from `child` using a copy constructor.

What's happening here is also called [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing), as the copy is a parent type, which does not have any of the members defined in the child class.